# pyspark dataframe failing to write out as parquet

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe called products_df.  When I try to write it out as parquet files I get the series of error messages below.  I've truncated the error messages because they're pretty long and repetitive with lots of verbose entries like "at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:202)".  It also struggles when trying to perform products_df.show().  pyspark can give me the products_df.count() and I have the output from products_df.schema below.  can anyone see what the issue might be from the error message below?

```
products_df.schema


StructType(List(StructField(id,IntegerType,true),StructField(amount,DecimalType(12,6),true),StructField(attributes,StringType,true),StructField(brandName,StringType,true),StructField(classification,StringType,true),StructField(descriptions,StringType,true),StructField(details,StringType,true),StructField(displayName,StringType,true),StructField(images,StringType,true),StructField(name,StringType,true),StructField(productShortCode,StringType,true),StructField(size,StringType,true),StructField(sku,StringType,true),StructField(subtype,StringType,true),StructField(tpc,StringType,true),StructField(type,StringType,true),StructField(uom,StringType,true),StructField(upc,StringType,true),StructField(createdAt,TimestampType,true),StructField(updatedAt,TimestampType,true),StructField(searchVector,StringType,true),StructField(ownerId,IntegerType,true),StructField(ownerType,StringType,true),StructField(barcodes,StringType,true),StructField(eCommerceName,StringType,true),StructField(externalId,StringType,true),StructField(packageTracked,BooleanType,true),StructField(msrp,DecimalType(16,6),true),StructField(cannabis,BooleanType,true),StructField(linkedTo,IntegerType,true),StructField(productOverrides,StringType,true),StructField(visible,BooleanType,true),StructField(mergedTo,IntegerType,true)))
```

code:

```
products_df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("path")
```

error:

```
An error was encountered:
An error occurred while calling o94.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    
...

Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.5 in stage 0.0 (TID 5, ip-10-240-93-69.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 8): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 8 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 160384 ms
Driver stacktrace:
    

...

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:822)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:171)
    ... 37 more

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 847, in parquet
    self._jwrite.parquet(path)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o94.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    
...

Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.5 in stage 0.0 (TID 5, ip-10-240-93-69.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 8): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 8 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 160384 ms
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2171)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2159)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:2158)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2158)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1011)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1011)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1011)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2368)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2357)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:822)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:171)
    ... 37 more
```